# Is there a Javascript library offering a declarative syntax for accessing nested keys through arrays?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to access nested keys inside Javascript objects:

```
type Cat = {
  name:  string
  human: Human
}

type Human = {
  name: string
}

const sophie: Cat = {name: 'Sophie', human: {name: 'Courtney'}}

>> console.log(_.get(sophie, 'human.name'))
Courtney
```

What if I the nested property I want is inside an array?

```
import {magicNestedGet} from 'unicorn'

type Cat = {
  name:   string
  humans: Human[]
}

const sophie: Cat = {name: 'Sophie', humans: [{name: 'Courtney'}, {name: 'Lukas'}]}

>> console.log(magicNestedGet(sophie, 'humans[].name')) // or maybe 'humans.name[]' ???
[Courtney, Lukas]
```

I thought lodash did this but I can't get it to work. Is there a library that supports a syntax like this?

Comment: Do you want all names or a specific one?

Comment: Have you tried  `_.get(sophie, 'human[0].name')`?

Comment: You can use destructuring syntax: `const { human: { name : [foo] } } = sophie; console.log(foo); // 'Courtney'`

Comment: I need the accessor to return *all* the nested properties as (nested) arrays, not to pick out a specific one. Destructuring works in a specific case, but in my case I need to specify the paths to nested resources declaratively, not in code. (The end goal is essentially a DSL for data transformation.)

Comment: Well, why not be the first to make said DSL? My NPM searches result in nothing of the sort.

Answer (score -1):

- Here's a solution function (credit to me):

```
function getPath(object: any, path: string): any {
    if (path[0] == "[") {
        path = path.substr(1);
        var index: int = 0;
        while (/\d/.test(path[0])) {
            index *= 10;
            index += parseInt(path[0]);
            path = path.substr(1);
        }
        path = path.substr(1);
        return getPath(object[index], path);
    }
    var pathNow: string = "";
    while (!".[".includes(path[0])) {
        pathNow += path[0];
        path = path.substr(1);
    }
    return getPath(object[pathNow], path);
}
```

- Or, unsafe but more features, use `eval`:

```
function getPathWithEval(object: any, path: string): any {
    var r: any;
    eval("r = object." + path);
    return r;
}
```

- Or, try, as [@connexo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73747980/is-there-a-javascript-library-offering-a-declarative-syntax-for-accessing-nested#comment130226169_73747980) says, use `<path>[<index>]<path>`